I am unable to connect with Facetime on my Monterey system, but the reverse works fine
I am unable to connect with Facetime on my Monterey system, but the reverse works fine.
That is, from my Sonoma system, it won't connect to my Monterey system, but from my Monterey system, I can connect with my Sonoma system. In Facetime Preferences, on the Monterey system, "You can be reached for Facetime at" is dimmed (though with my right e-mail and box checked). I have to assume this is telling me that I can't be reached by Facetime on that Monterey system.
How do I fix this?
I am logged into my Apple account on that system, so it isn't matter of my Monterey Mac not knowing who I am.
I should say that I can get Facetime calls on my Monterey system, but I need to manually open the Facetime app on it to get it to connect. What does NOT happen, is for Facetime to open automatically when a call comes in, and I get a accept/deny notification at top right. Yes, Facetime notifications are enabled.
